# CDE: how to properly convert a jpeg image to xpm for use on wallpaper?

Tags: conversion, jpeg

I want to convert a jpeg image to use on CDE as wallpaper.
Take my jpeg(originally is hd 1920x1024)
rescale to 320x240 with gimp
convert to 8bit with convert

```
convert 9.jpg -colors=256 9.xpm
```

Then put in $HOME/.dt/backdrops
I can see in preview,but when i click apply on dtstyle...
nothing happen.
What i miss?

Some image works,some other no,for example this converted as xpm works fine

[image]

Other images of nature-wallpapers no

I forgot: happen only on VNC X server,maybe a problem of VNC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing your XPM files, but I suspect your usage of the GIMP to reduce the resolution is not being done correctly. Alternately, if you are genuinely worrying about 8-bit color depth, you need to actually reduce to fewer than 256 colors. The window manager itself (CDE) needs some colors, as do other programs.

Traditionally, we used to use a 6x6x6 color cube (216 colors) on our old 8-bit color X-terminals back in the 1990s. You can convert an image to XPM, rescale it to 320x240, and reduce the number of colors all in one command:

```
convert foo.jpg -geometry 320x240 -colors 216 foo.xpm
```

If 216 doesn't work, try it again with an even smaller number of colors and let us know what value worked for you.

---

By the way, if you find you have 8-bit colormap swapping problems (colors of other apps change drastically when you switch programs), maybe try the "netscape colormap" which is made of up of 216 "web safe" colors.

```
convert 9.jpg -geometry 320x240 -remap netscape: 9.xpm
```